# How to store value globally?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, 2d, 2d-games

The code will store the x1 and y1 variables, but they revert back to their original 0.0 value as soon as the touchesEnded function begins. I want these values to remain after the touchesBegan function ends. How can I store these values?

```
var x1: CGFloat = 0.0
var y1: CGFloat = 0.0
var x2: CGFloat = 0.0
var y2: CGFloat = 0.0

//touch initialized
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        var x1 = location.x
        var y1 = location.y
        print(x1,y1)
    }
}

//touch ends
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        print(x1,y1)
        let location2 = touch.location(in: self)
        let x2 = location2.x
        let y2 = location2.y
        let originX = min(x1,x2)
        let originY = min(y1,y2)
        let cornerX = max(x1,x2)
        let cornerY = max(y1,y2)
        let boxWidth = cornerX - originX
        let boxHeight = cornerY - originY

        let box = SKSpriteNode()
        box.size = CGSize(width: boxWidth, height: boxHeight)
        box.color = SKColor.black
        box.position = CGPoint(x:originX, y: originY)
        addChild(box)

        print(x1,y1,x2,y2)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you declare 2 variable CGPoints instead of 4 CGFloats?

Comment: BTW you should change your question title as you are not trying to make a property GLOBAL. You want to change your class properties using its methods

Comment: @Leo From his point of view he is trying to make then global, so I think the title stands. I don't think he realises that variable can have local, class or global scope and that he wants a class property rather than a true global var.

Comment: Did you not look at my answer on your other question? It already has class variables

Comment: I would recommend the use of a Singleton pattern which stores those values in a settings class accessible from anywhere in your project and with the guarantee that only one instance of the settings object and therefore just one instance of the values inside of it are in memory.

Answer (score 4):

you are redeclaring them inside each function. so they remain local to that function.  declare them outside as you have done at top, then set value inside function.  It may not be necessary to use self, but it is a good idea as it lets you know that the variable you are playing with is from outside the closure.

```
var x1: CGFloat = 0.0
var y1: CGFloat = 0.0
var x2: CGFloat = 0.0
var y2: CGFloat = 0.0

//touch initialized
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
for touch in touches{
let location = touch.location(in: self)
self.x1 = location.x
self.y1 = location.y
print(x1,y1)

    }
}

//touch ends
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?){
for touch in touches{

print(x1,y1)
let location2 = touch.location(in: self)
self.x2 = location2.x
self.y2 = location2.y
let originX = min(self.x1,self.x2)
let originY = min(self.y1,self.y2)
let cornerX = max(self.x1,self.x2)
let cornerY = max(self.y1,self.y2)
let boxWidth = cornerX - originX
let boxHeight = cornerY - originY

let box = SKSpriteNode()
box.size = CGSize(width: boxWidth, height: boxHeight)
box.color = SKColor.black
box.position = CGPoint(x:originX, y: originY)
addChild(box)

print(self.x1,self.y1,self.x2,self.y2)
```

Answer (score 1):

change it to without a var inside the function. with a var you make a local variable which hides the class/global varibale:

```
//touch initialized
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

  for touch in touches{
    let location = touch.location(in: self)
    x1 = location.x
    y1 = location.y
    print(x1,y1)

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This tripped me up a few times too.

Swift 3 silently (without even a warning) [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) your properties (or globals - I'm only guessing it's a class from the method names) with `touchesBegan()` method's local variables:

> In computer programming, variable shadowing occurs when a variable
>   declared within a certain scope (decision block, method, or inner
>   class) has the same name as a variable declared in an outer scope.

You can remove the `var` or `let` declarations to make it work:

```
x1 = location.x
y1 = location.y
```

..or you can explicitly qualify the properties with `self` to make it more clear:

```
self.x1 = location.x
self.y1 = location.y
```

There seem to be a few discussions around this implicit shadowing behaviour, which makes me think it might change in the future: https://google.com/search?q=variable+shadow+site:swift.org